# Android deep sleep and wake locks

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I have created an android app which runs fine in all phones. But in my Alcatel phone it doesn't as the phone goes to a deep sleep mode and the data network fails so the app doesn't get a data network and doesn't sync the data from the server .

---

My Design ...

`SystemBootReceiver` --> `(DataSyncService)Service` --> `(MyBroadcastReceiver)BroadcastReceiver` --> `(MyDataService)Service` .

So here on system boot I start `DataSyncService` where I set up the `AlarmManager` (repeated) and call the `MyBroadcastRecever`. After calling the `BroadcastRecever` I stop `DataSyncService` by calling `stopself()` .

Now the `MyBroadcastRecever` calls the `MyDataService`.

---

I came across WakeLocks which as said prevent the phone from going in deep sleep mode.
So I implemented it inside `MyDataService` `onCreate()` method

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
                    getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

And `release()` the wake lock before stopping the service.

I have also set the permission in android Manifest.

But this didn't work. So for a quick check I used [WAKE LOCK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.wl&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImV1LnRoZWRhcmtlbi53bCJd) app from the market .

But this also didn't wake the phone up. Again I came across WAKE MY ANDROID (app removed from store) app from market and installed it .. and a magic happened here.

It kept the phone alive.

As the description in this app says that they have also used a `Wake Lock`. So what am I missing then ?

Is there an implementation mistake or a design issue ?

Comment: Perhaps, you could try [ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP) flag with SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? The problem is that network requests fail when the app runs after waking up the device?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D yes i have solved the problem with the answer you gave . thanks , also i came across WakefulBroadcastReceiver
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lock you have in your service never runs - cause your service is never run

Well - you have to use a [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) - make your `MyDataService` extend `WakefulIntentService` and in your receiver call `WakefulIntentService.doWakefulWork(context, MyDataService.class)`

Or implement a static lock shared by both your service and receiver - which would be tricky.

If using wifi you should also need to use a `WifiLock` - *inside* your wakeful intent service - can get tricky

Comment: I think the asker indicated their service does run but that there is a network error.

Comment: @satur9nine:"But in my Alcatel phone it doesn't as the phone goes to a deep sleep mode..." - please revert

Comment: Mr_and_Mrs_D:"But in my Alcatel phone it doesn't as the phone goes to a deep sleep mode and the data network falls so the app doesn't get a data network and doesn't sync the data from the server ." I see the problem as being "app doesn't get a data network"

Comment: @satur9nine:it's not - and even then he will need wifi locks - BUT AFTER the CPU is awake, obviously. Fair play please

Comment: My vote is locked in by StackOverflow I cannot change it. Using a WifiManager.WifiLock is a more useful suggestion, but only works if the user is in range of Wi-Fi.

Comment: @satur9nine: the problem is he does not keep the phone awake - mobile data would but I bet he is using wireless - and now you can change your vote :)

Comment: I don't think he wants to keep the phone awake forever, he just wants it to wake up periodically, use some network and go back to sleep.

Comment: @satur9nine:Yes exactly that is what the Wakeful_IntentService_ is for - the lock is disposed as soon as the service returns - a simple intent service won't run probably - check the links I posted - thanks for upvote :)