# WakefulIntentService implementation clarifications

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice, commonsware-cwac

Commonsware's [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) works beautifully but there are some things  I do not quite get. Below is the core of the service - a stripped down version of the [source](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/wakeful/WakefulIntentService.java) :

```
class WIS extends IntentService {

    private static final String NAME = WIS.class.getName() + ".Lock";
    private static volatile WakeLock lockStatic = null;

    synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
        if (lockStatic == null) {
            PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            lockStatic = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, NAME);
            lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
        }
        return (lockStatic);
    }

    public static void startWIS(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        getLock(ctxt.getApplicationContext()).acquire();
        ctxt.startService(i);
    }

    public WIS(String name) {
        super(name);
        setIntentRedelivery(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        PowerManager.WakeLock lock = getLock(this.getApplicationContext());
        if (!lock.isHeld() || (flags & START_FLAG_REDELIVERY) != 0) { // ?
            lock.acquire();
        }
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return (START_REDELIVER_INTENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            // do your thing
        } finally {
            PowerManager.WakeLock lock = getLock(this.getApplicationContext());
            if (lock.isHeld()) lock.release();
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- What happens if the process is killed just after the `onReceive()` of our alarm receiver returns ? That is if service `onCreate()` (if the service is not already instantiated) or `onStartCommand()` never run. AFAIK a process killed takes its locks with it. Or is this an impossible scenario ?
- In view of the previous should `(flags & START_FLAG_RETRY)` be added ?
- Why the `if (!lock.isHeld())` check ?
- Why is `this.getApplicationContext()` needed ?  is not `this` enough ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> AFAIK a process killed takes its locks with it.

Correct.

> Or is this an impossible scenario ?

It's fairly unlikely, but certainly not impossible.

> In view of the previous should (flags & START_FLAG_RETRY) be added ?

That should be covered by `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY`. AFAIK, with `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, there is no `RETRY` without `REDELIVERY`. If you have evidence to the contrary, I'd love to see it.

> Why the if (!lock.isHeld()) check ?

Calling `release()` on a `WakeLock` that is not held results in an exception. This is just a safety blanket to ensure we don't wind up throwing an unnecessary exception. In theory, it should never be needed; in theory, I should have hair.

> Why is this.getApplicationContext() needed ? is not this enough ?

We create a `WakeLock`, which we hold in a static data member. *Probably* the `getSystemService()` call does not wind up putting the `Context` that called it inside the `PowerManager`. And, even if it did, *probably* the `Context` would not be passed to the resulting `WakeLock` instance. However, to be safe, by using `getApplicationContext()`, we obtain the `WakeLock` in a fashion that ensures that the only `Context` we could possibly "leak" is the singleton application context, which, as a singleton, is effectively pre-leaked. :-)

Comment: "If you have evidence to the contrary, I'd love to see it." - not a bit, just the docs are not clear that when START_FLAG_RETRY is set then START_FLAG_REDELIVERY is also set

Comment: A- important - if the scenario I describe happens and onCreate (or even the Constructor where we `setRedeliverIntent(true)`) did not run - we loose ? Or the system will run the `onStartCommand` with START_FLAG_RETRY ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: "the docs are not clear that when START_FLAG_RETRY is set then START_FLAG_REDELIVERY is also set " -- `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY` is set when `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` is used, and I am not aware of a case where I would ever see `START_FLAG_RETRY` on its own. "this initialization of reference fields to null is needed ?" -- no, that's personal coding style. "if the scenario I describe happens" -- I have no idea what would happen in that case, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare while performing network operation on `wakefulintentservice` it throws `NetworkonMainThread` Exception ??

Comment: @Ryderz: No, it won't. Partly, that is because `WakefulIntentService` does not do any network I/O itself. Partly, that is because `doWakefulWork()` is called on a background thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! But everytime my activity re-launches `wakeupservice` gets restarted, not able to detect whether running or not?

Comment: HI @CommonsWare Is this useful library compatible with apps target Android Oreo?

Comment: @RajeshK: `WakefulIntentService` has been discontinued. Use `JobIntentService` (or `WorkManager`, once it reaches 1.0.0 -- it is still `1.0.0-beta1` right now).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry don't have enough rep to comment but it looks like you have a race condition with the two checks if(held)release and if(!held)acquire. I.e. making the ref volatile is not enough to guard you against races.

These are composite statements invoked on different threads. You likely want to enter a sync block on a private final Object lock = new Object() for those two checks so they are done atomically. Very corner-y but thought I'd mention it. Let me know if you disagree. Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare: this is for you I think