# Implementing awake lock on a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms, android-wake-lock

I am calling  a service from an AlarmManager onReceive, below is the implementation. I want to know if this implementation of  a wake lock is fine and will it suffice my needs?

This is the onStart function in my Service Class:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    WakeLock wakeLock = null;
    try{
        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        //For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it? If so, does it work? You haven't explained anything about how your service works or what it does or what your "needs" are. Also `onStart(...)` was deprecated in API 5 - you should be using `onStartCommand(...)`.

Comment: Yes I have tried it and that is why I posted it here to know if i am missing something, this works under normal conditions but the prime reason of posting was to know about its execution in cases other than the 'normal' ones.

Comment: See like you pointed out about deprecation :) I have isolated the code into a second project, to check on functionality, right now thge service only displays a toast message but in actual program it will be implemented to do some huge database manuplation which I intend to be doing in a background thread, also in this case I want to know if I can use an async task and cancel the wakelock in postExecute?

Comment: You may need a null check in finally - also do not catch Exception it is considered bad style - catch the specific exceptions thrown

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that should work fine. Although it won't work if you spin up a new Thread, in that case `wakelock.release()` will be called before the Thread finishes.

You might want to check CommonsWare's [Wakeful service](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) though. That services handles the wakelock for you, ensuring that you have a Wakelock during the service, and it'll release it as soon as you stop the service.

Comment: Thanks for the insight mate :) can I implement an async task and just cancel the wake lock in onPostExecute?

Comment: @user2822178: Yes go for [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) - do not reinvent the wheel - moreover there are various subtle points : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074035/wakefulintentservice-implementation-clarifications

Comment: Thanks, that is an insightful post!