# PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am very confused whether to acquire this wakelock. E.g. I have this type of code that is called from `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiever` (CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE, BOOT_COMPLETED etc) **asynchronously** i.e. I am launching an `IntentService` from `onReceive()` which performs heavy lifting.

```
private static void insertInDatabase(Context context /*, some data to be inserted in database*/) {
        Database helper = Database.getInstance(context);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        final WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, wakelockName); 
        wakeLock.acquire();
        try { 
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            // insert data in database here  
        } finally {
            wakeLock.release();
        }
    }
```

Is this scenario the right candidate to acquire `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`?

Comment: see my answer - won't work if you just acquire the lock in the service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by @paha misses an important point : IntentService is not enough. Between `onReceive()` ends and the IntentService is started the phone might fall asleep again. You need a (static) lock to bridge this gap - this is implemented in Mark Murpphy's [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)

So keep the AlarmManager and receiver but launch a *`WakefulIntentService`* from your `onReceive()`.

See:

- [Android deep sleep and wake locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417541/android-deep-sleep-and-wake-locks/16268293#16268293)
- [PowerManager wakelock not waking device up from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471028/powermanager-wakelock-not-waking-device-up-from-service/17496029#17496029)

Comment: Exactly, that was my concern and infact I have static wakelock implemented already because `startService()` is not synchronous. The code in question is just the sample code to explain. I was just curious if its the right scenario to acquire wakelock. Because I couldn't find many samples using it and its hard to produce the problem manually.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh: so you start your service _with a static method inside on receive that also acquires the lock_ ?

Comment: yes, that static method is responsible for starting `IntentService` but it acquires a wakelock before calling `startService()`. So the lock is static as well.

Comment: which is right way, right? Its just that our app was showing a bit more wake lock time then we expect it to have. We are using Wake lock detector apps and also analyzing from Battery option from Android Settings. So I thought why not get a social validation as well.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh: great still you may be better of with WIS - see :http://stackoverflow.com/a/17496029/281545 for the skeleton (which is what you do hopefully) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074035/wakefulintentservice-implementation-clarifications for some fine points

Comment: yes `WakefulIntentService` is doing same thing as well, it just have some utility methods for `AlarmManager` which we don't need. 
Thank you for your time brother.

Answer (score 2):

Method `onReceive(`) is running on the main application thread and you do not know how long `insertInDatabase()` will take.
Use an `IntentService` for doing the database insert and scheduling your alarms. The `IntentService` will call your `onHandleIntent()` on a background thread, so you can take the time you need, and the service automatically goes away when `onHandleIntent()` completes.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        final WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, wakelockName); 
        wakeLock.acquire();
        wl.acquire();
        try { 
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            // insert data in database here  
        } finally {
            wakeLock.release();
        }
    }
}
```

To start `IntentService` from `BroadcastReceiver` use `AlarmManager`.
`IntentService` work as queue pattern and you don't need to worry about synchronicity of operations.

*Added after discussion in comments:*

Your code example does not say from what place you call `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. The short answer is `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` is not needed in the `BroadcastReciever` and `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` is needed in the `IntentService`. Maybe this will help [BroadcastReceiver, Service and Wakelock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681071/broadcastreceiver-service-and-wakelock)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess you have missed my point here, I am already launching an `IntentService` in `onReceive()`. My question is do I need `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` here or not?

Comment: Let me clarify that in question as well, although  I used the word asynchronously.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh I updated the answer by adding some information. Maybe I not fully understand your question, please give details, if you do not find an answer.

Comment: My question is do I need `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` here or not? My question is not about internal working of `IntentService` or is `onRecive()` is called on UI thread or not by default etc.

In other words, my question is "If in deep sleep, Android wakes up send a broadcast. Can it go to sleep immediately again? even tough I launched a service from `onReceive()`? Will Android wait for my service to finish or do I need to explicitly ask for `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`." I guess I can't be more clearer that that.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh Your code example does not say from what place you call PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. The short answer is LOCK is not needed in the BroadcastReciever and LOCK is needed in the IntentService. Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681071/broadcastreceiver-service-and-wakelock

Comment: Please post your last comment as answer so I can accept it. Thanks for the link. All I needed was asocial validation to be sure that I am doing things correctly.